# Send email as HTML using SMTPMail plugin

Tags: php, email

My server sends a routine email to a list of people every now and then. I'd like to be bale to send it as HTML. I know I need to use `$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";` or something like that, however I also use a little plugin I found a while back that allows me to connect to the SMTP server before sending the mail (so it doesn't come up as spam in inboxes and what not).

Anyway, anyone know how I can edit the plugin to make it send as HTML?

Mailing script:

```
include('SMTPconfig.php');
include('SMTPClass.php');
$emailbody='I\'d like this to send as html';
$elist = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM `subs` ORDER BY id ASC");
 if(mysql_num_rows($elist) > 0)
  {
  while($elist_result = mysql_fetch_array($elist))
  {
    $to= $elist_result['email']; 
    $from = 'admin@chloecrayola.co.uk';
    $subject = $_POST['sub'];
    $body = $emailbody;
    $SMTPMail = new SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from, $to, $subject, $body);
    $SMTPChat = $SMTPMail->SendMail();
    }
    exit();
   }
```

Config file:

```
$SmtpServer="mail.chloecrayola.co.uk";
$SmtpPort="25";
$SmtpUser="admin@chloecrayola.co.uk";
$SmtpPass="*******";
```

And finally, the bit that sends the emails. I need to make changes here, but I don't know how I'd do it:

```
class SMTPClient
{
function SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from, $to, $subject, $body)
{
$this->SmtpServer = $SmtpServer;
$this->SmtpUser = base64_encode ($SmtpUser);
$this->SmtpPass = base64_encode ($SmtpPass);
$this->from = $from;
$this->to = $to;
$this->subject = $subject;
$this->body = $body;
    if ($SmtpPort == "") 
    {
    $this->PortSMTP = 25;
        }else{
    $this->PortSMTP = $SmtpPort;
    }
}
function SendMail ()
{

    if ($SMTPIN = fsockopen ($this->SmtpServer, $this->PortSMTP)) 
    {

           fputs ($SMTPIN, "EHLO ".$HTTP_HOST."\r\n");  
           $talk["hello"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 ); 

           fputs($SMTPIN, "auth login\r\n");
           $talk["res"]=fgets($SMTPIN,1024);
            fputs($SMTPIN, $this->SmtpUser."\r\n");
            $talk["user"]=fgets($SMTPIN,1024);

            fputs($SMTPIN, $this->SmtpPass."\r\n");
            $talk["pass"]=fgets($SMTPIN,256);

           fputs ($SMTPIN, "MAIL FROM: <".$this->from.">\r\n");  
           $talk["From"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 );  
           fputs ($SMTPIN, "RCPT TO: <".$this->to.">\r\n");  
           $talk["To"] = fgets ($SMTPIN, 1024); 

           fputs($SMTPIN, "DATA\r\n");
            $talk["data"]=fgets( $SMTPIN,1024 );

            fputs($SMTPIN, "To: <".$this->to.">\r\nFrom: <".$this->from.">\r\nSubject:".$this->subject."\r\n\r\n\r\n".$this->body."\r\n.\r\n");
            $talk["send"]=fgets($SMTPIN,256);
           //CLOSE CONNECTION AND EXIT ... 
           fputs ($SMTPIN, "QUIT\r\n");  
           fclose($SMTPIN); 
    }  
return $talk;
}        
}
```

I'm sure it must be possible to do, but I literally have no clue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="===boundaryString=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Try to use the above MIME header in $headers.

Then the body needs to include the following:

```
--===boundaryString==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

...
text template
...

--===boundaryString==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


...
html template
...
```

It is always a good practice to include both txt and html templates containing the same information formatted as txt and as HTML. Helps avoiding the spam filters and improves the overall delivery. Still this is not a substitute for a proper reverse lookup setup which includes SPF, DKIM, DMARK records on your DNS server.

Comment: My problem here is that I can't seem to find a way to modify headers. As soon as I try to add anything to do with headers, a load of (non fatal) errors pop up. Since posting this question, I've found a new plug in to complete this task, although if anyone does come up with an answer for this, it may be useful in the future

Comment: You can try to add the header I proposed at the beginning of the body. It should override the existing header added by the plug-in.